# Is it possible to connect to a server DB from Windows Mobile App

Tags: database, visual-studio, windows-mobile, odbc, adodb

Is there any way that I can connect to a server DB (Oracle, MS SQL, Sybase, ...) from a Windows Mobile application (written in C# using VS 2008). Is there support for say ODBC or another technologie? I'm connecting to a LAN via WLAN or via UMTS.

There is no possibility for me to install an additional server component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure [System.Data.SqlClient](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173281.aspx) for SQL Server works just fine. For Oracle there's [OraDirect](http://www.componentsource.com/products/dotconnect-for-oracle/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that no.
[OdbcConnection members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection_members.aspx) are not marked with Compact Framework support flag http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/6xk89yz6.CFW(en-us,VS.90).gif

Check out [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx): it shares a common API with the other Microsoft SQL Server editions. It also includes ADO.NET providers for data access using ADO.NET APIs, and built-in synchronization capabilities (from WikiPedia)

Answer (score 1):

No, the only direct connectivity option in CE is System.Data.SqlClient, which only works for SQL Server.

I've only done it using a purpose-built socket server - which has the benefit of enabling you to turn it into a useful abstraction layer, but is a medium-sized bit of work. Portable to any tcpip networkable client device, however. You can also then make it asynchronous which is almost required in a mobile environment.